Wagtail override serve method in the custom Page that inherits RoutablePageMixin
I have a custom CacheMixin class in wagtail.
class CacheMixin:
    def serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().serve(request, *args, **kwargs)
        # the rest of the cache implementation

These basically how my custom page models looks like:
class BasePage(CacheMixin, Page):
    #some fields

    def serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().serve(request, *args, **kwargs)
        self._perform_some_ops()
        return response


class CustomPage(
    RoutablePageMixin,
    BasePage,
):
    # some fields

    @route('my_route/<int:category_id>')
    def my_route(self, category_id):
        # my route logic
        return self.render(
            request,
            extra_context={
                "key1": value_1,
                "key2": value_2
            },
            template="my_app/category.html"
        )

The problem is my_route/ is not cached.
If I try to change the orders in the CustomPage class like this: CustomPage(BasePage,RoutablePageMixin), the route is not accessible.
I tried overriding the serve method inside the CustomPage model:
def serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    super(RoutablePageMixin, self).serve(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return BasePage.serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

But again the route is not accessible. What did I miss here?
How can I resolve it?

I did something similar by overriding the render method from RoutablePageMixin. Here is a gist of my implementation.

As I understand RoutablePageMixin's render method is acting like a serve method, right?
So we need to override it and do a cache operation there.
@gasman usually answers questions here, I think if he sees it, he will confirm it. Maybe it needs to be change
